# jQuery "Each" function values

Tags: jquery, ajax

So, I have the original AJAX function:

```
dataType: 'json',
data : { action: something , id: id}, 
success: function(data) {
    var my_title= data.title; // values: "post1,post2,post3"      
    var my_name = data.name;  // values: "steve,mike,sean"
    var my_html ='<div class="'+ my_title +'">'+ my_name +'</div>' 
    jQuery('.my_class').append(my_html); 
}
```

So, I have two variables (`my_titles` and `my_name`) each with 3 values (`n` number values).

Then, I want to use these individual values for `my_html` variable and append them in the `.my_class`.

The result will be as follow:

```
 <div class="my_class">
    <div class="post1">Steve</div>
    <div class="post2">mike</div>
    <div class="post3">sean</div>
 </div>
```

So, I tried to edit my AJAX function as below:

```
dataType: 'json',
data : { action: something , id: id}, 
success: function(data) {
   jQuery.each(data,function (i,n){     
        var my_title= n.title;
        var my_name = n.name;               
        alert("Title:" + my_title);             
    });
}
```

I am getting `undefined` as the result.

Any help? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it like following.

```
jQuery.each(data.title, function (index){        
    var my_title = this; // change here `this` instead of `data.title`               
    alert("Title:" + my_title);             
});
```

If `data.title` is a string. You need to `split` `data.title` and then iterate through it like following.

```
jQuery.each(data.title.split(','), function (index){        
    var my_title= this;               
    alert("Title:" + my_title);             
});
```

**Update:** Do like following in `ajax` success.

```
var length=data.title.length;
for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {    
    var my_title= data.title[i];
    var my_name = data.name[i];               
    alert("Title:" + my_title); 
    alert("Name:" + my_name);             
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. i made an edit to the original post. I realized that I had the form wrong to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data.title is an array

```
jQuery.each(data.title, function (index){        
    var my_title= data.title[index];               
    alert("Title:" + my_title);             
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I made changes to the original post. Could you take a look at it for me?